# Why would the first element in this array be empty?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm wondering why the first element in this array would be empty?

```
$first_names[] = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) { 
  $first_names[] = $row['first_name'];
}
```

The result of `var_dump($first_names);` is:

```
array(15) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> string(5) "Johny" [2]=> string(5) "Jacob" ...}
```

Comment: Technically, it's not empty; rather, it holds an empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
$first_names[] = array();
```

is explicitly pushing an empty array onto the front of `$first_names`. That's what `$array[]=...` does; it's a synonym for `array_push`.

I think your intention was to initialize the variable to an empty array. For this you'd simply use the assignment operator:

```
$first_names = array();
```

Comment: You're absolutely right :-D Quick question - I noticed that I need to include it in the foreach loop when I create a subarray - why is that?  $students[] = array($row['first_name'], $row['last_name']);

Answer (score 6):

`$first_names[] = array();`

should be

`$first_names = array();`

Answer (score 2):

Initialize array as

```
$first_names = array();
```

Answer (score 2):

It is empty because you are adding an array element to the 0th index in the `$first_names` variable.

You should try

```
$first_names = array();
```